# Why isn't my SVG displaying correctly in IE1 or /Edge?

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge, display

I exported an illustration as SVG using Adobe Illustrator and wish to use it on a website. The SVG is displayed correctly in Google Chrome:

[image: SVG displayed in Google Chrome]

**but not** in Internet Explorer 11 or Microsoft Edge 40:

[image: SVG displayed in IE 11 / Edge]

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 3840 2160">

<defs>

<linearGradient id="a" x1="1098.8" y1="1250.05" x2="1372.02" y2="1250.05" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="gray"/>
<stop offset="0.1" stop-color="#8f8f8f"/>
<stop offset="0.52" stop-color="#cbcbcb"/>
<stop offset="0.84" stop-color="#f1f1f1"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff"/>
</linearGradient>

<linearGradient id="b" x1="949.29" y1="2007.84" x2="1561.63" y2="2015.91" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="gray"/>
<stop offset="0.15" stop-color="#9b9b9b"/>
<stop offset="0.41" stop-color="#c6c6c6"/>
<stop offset="0.66" stop-color="#e5e5e5"/>
<stop offset="0.86" stop-color="#f8f8f8"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff"/>
</linearGradient>

<linearGradient id="c" x1="2167.21" y1="1714.96" x2="1710.54" y2="1908.61" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#999"/>
<stop offset="0.18" stop-color="#b9b9b9"/>
<stop offset="0.4" stop-color="#d8d8d8"/>
<stop offset="0.61" stop-color="#ededed"/>
<stop offset="0.81" stop-color="#fbfbfb"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff"/>
</linearGradient>

<linearGradient id="d" x1="1647.4" y1="1612.59" x2="1275.61" y2="1770.24" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/>
<stop offset="0.34" stop-color="#fdfdfd"/>
<stop offset="0.5" stop-color="#f5f5f5"/>
<stop offset="0.63" stop-color="#e8e8e8"/>
<stop offset="0.74" stop-color="#d5d5d5"/>
<stop offset="0.84" stop-color="#bdbdbd"/>
<stop offset="0.92" stop-color="#a0a0a0"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="gray"/>
</linearGradient>

<linearGradient id="e" x1="1709.57" y1="1594.73" x2="2109.2" y2="1594.73" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/>
<stop offset="0.52" stop-color="#f4f4f4"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#e6e6e6"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="f" x1="2527.59" y1="1316.91" x2="2890.2" y2="1316.91" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/>
<stop offset="0.19" stop-color="#fbfbfb"/>
<stop offset="0.39" stop-color="#ededed"/>
<stop offset="0.6" stop-color="#d8d8d8"/>
<stop offset="0.82" stop-color="#b9b9b9"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#999"/>
</linearGradient>

<linearGradient id="g" x1="2273.36" y1="1546.94" x2="2527.59" y2="1546.94" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#999"/>
<stop offset="0.24" stop-color="#b9b9b9"/>
<stop offset="0.57" stop-color="#dfdfdf"/>
<stop offset="0.83" stop-color="#f6f6f6"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff"/>
</linearGradient>

<linearGradient id="h" x1="1427.73" y1="1215.06" x2="1810.4" y2="1215.06" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="gray"/>
<stop offset="0.05" stop-color="#8f8f8f"/>
<stop offset="0.17" stop-color="#b1b1b1"/>
<stop offset="0.29" stop-color="#cecece"/>
<stop offset="0.43" stop-color="#e3e3e3"/>
<stop offset="0.58" stop-color="#f3f3f3"/>
<stop offset="0.75" stop-color="#fcfcfc"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff"/>
</linearGradient>

<linearGradient id="i" x1="2399.58" y1="1152.08" x2="2556.87" y2="1152.08" xlink:href="#f"/>

<linearGradient id="j" x1="2490.22" y1="1078.88" x2="2609.25" y2="1078.88" xlink:href="#f"/>

<linearGradient id="k" x1="2558.22" y1="1091.26" x2="2627.37" y2="1090.73" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/>
<stop offset="0.26" stop-color="#f9f9f9"/>
<stop offset="0.59" stop-color="#e9e9e9"/>
<stop offset="0.96" stop-color="#cfcfcf"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#ccc"/>
</linearGradient>

<linearGradient id="l" x1="2577.37" y1="1130.63" x2="2662.72" y2="1129.98" xlink:href="#k"/>

<linearGradient id="m" x1="2242.34" y1="1912.74" x2="1518.04" y2="742.98" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/>
<stop offset="0.1" stop-color="#f0fef5"/>
<stop offset="0.52" stop-color="#b6fcd0"/>
<stop offset="0.83" stop-color="#92fbb9"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#84fab0"/>
</linearGradient>

</defs>

<title>svg</title>

<g style="isolation:isolate">

<path d="M2535.2,1261.46c-43.64,42.91-77.89,86.79-90.84,86.79-3.25-.67-4.71-2.42-4.71-5v50.19c0,2.61,1.46,4.35,4.71,5,7.46,0,22-14.56,41.3-35.11v45.56c0,2.24,1.36,3.71,4.37,4.28a7.6,7.6,0,0,0,2.69.46c8.57,0,22.6-11.72,39.66-28.75v38.74c0,2.32,1.45,3.89,4.65,4.58a9.9,9.9,0,0,0,2.76.38c27.92,0,100.35-102.12,159.33-137.56v-50.19c-59,35.44-131.41,137.56-159.33,137.56-.32,0-.63,0-.94-.06,34.71-35.64,79.85-88.55,117.34-111.22a19.41,19.41,0,0,1,.71,5.32v-50.19a19.29,19.29,0,0,0-.71-5.31c-14.82,9-30.84,22.65-46.94,38.13V1205a19.68,19.68,0,0,0-.26-3.21c-18,10.68-35.53,24.48-52.13,39.32v-42a7.16,7.16,0,0,0-.49-2.72c-71.58,49-164.41,125.82-180.6,170a39.84,39.84,0,0,0-3.23,15.85v50.19a39.81,39.81,0,0,1,3.23-15.85C2390.4,1376.67,2467.63,1310.08,2535.2,1261.46Zm74.05-6.4c-48.06,46.22-96.8,108.38-116.53,108.38a7.6,7.6,0,0,1-2.69-.46,6.81,6.81,0,0,1-2.92-1.19c31.51-33.58,75.3-82.15,121.88-109.84A19.67,19.67,0,0,1,2609.25,1255.06Z" style="fill:#006e7e"/><path d="M2383.42,1431.87c-63.3,69-127.15,151.09-171.72,211.09h0c-25.43-63.24-36.74-120.61-36.74-172.62v50.19c0,52,11.31,109.38,36.74,172.62,44.57-60,108.42-142.14,171.72-211.09Z" style="fill:#006e7e"/><path d="M2273.36,1660.39v50.19c493.93-122.51,616.84-310.5,616.84-460.49V1199.9C2890.2,1349.89,2767.29,1537.88,2273.36,1660.39Z" style="fill:#006e7e"/><path d="M1957.87,1542.16c-25.25-14.32-6-51.85-50.41-77l-190.67-108.07c-68.46-38.79-165.43-58-231.45-58-24.47,0-44.69,2.64-57.62,7.91v50.19c12.93-5.27,33.15-7.91,57.62-7.91,66,0,163,19.23,231.45,58l190.67,108.07c44.38,25.15,25.16,62.68,50.41,77,66,37.42,114.46,68.39,185.1,108.44,8.16,4.62,16.48,9.19,24.88,13.71v-50.19c-8.4-4.52-16.72-9.09-24.88-13.71C2072.33,1610.55,2023.9,1579.59,1957.87,1542.16Z" style="fill:#006e7e"/><path d="M1098.79,1137.17v50.19c0,165.7,135.34,483.1,912.18,549.21-131.77,30.76-299.74,71.44-428.33,107.6-6.48,0-12.81.32-19.18.32-18.27,0-36.73-2.21-55.9-4.43s-39.13-4.42-60.32-4.42a258.59,258.59,0,0,0-52.37,5.12c-71.65,14.7-147.44,56.85-147.44,87.8v50.18c0-30.94,75.79-73.09,147.44-87.79a258.59,258.59,0,0,1,52.37-5.12c21.19,0,41.12,2.21,60.32,4.42s37.63,4.43,55.9,4.43c6.37,0,12.7-.27,19.18-.32,154.13-43.35,364.86-93.18,502-124.65V1742q12.2.75,24.55,1.43v-50.19C1245.39,1646.39,1098.79,1309.63,1098.79,1137.17Z" style="fill:#006e7e"/><path d="M1296.32,2103.21c-146.26,0-272-21.27-346.52-40.08v50.19c74.47,18.81,200.26,40.08,346.52,40.08,263.78,0,594.16-69.19,810.37-346.82v-50.19C1890.48,2034,1560.1,2103.21,1296.32,2103.21Z" style="fill:#006e7e"/><path d="M2535.2,1212.36c-43.64,42.91-77.89,86.79-90.84,86.79-3.25-.67-4.71-2.41-4.71-5v50.19c0,2.61,1.46,4.35,4.71,5,7.46,0,22-14.56,41.3-35.1v45.55c0,2.24,1.36,3.71,4.37,4.28a7.6,7.6,0,0,0,2.69.46c8.57,0,22.6-11.71,39.66-28.75v38.74c0,2.32,1.45,3.89,4.65,4.58a9.54,9.54,0,0,0,2.76.38c27.92,0,100.35-102.12,159.33-137.56v-50.19c-59,35.44-131.41,137.56-159.33,137.56-.32,0-.63,0-.94-.06,34.71-35.64,79.85-88.55,117.34-111.22a19.41,19.41,0,0,1,.71,5.32v-50.19a19.29,19.29,0,0,0-.71-5.31c-14.82,9-30.84,22.65-46.94,38.13v-50.09a19.87,19.87,0,0,0-.26-3.21c-18,10.69-35.53,24.48-52.13,39.32v-42a7.18,7.18,0,0,0-.49-2.73c-71.58,49-164.41,125.82-180.6,170a39.84,39.84,0,0,0-3.23,15.85v50.19a39.81,39.81,0,0,1,3.23-15.85C2390.4,1327.57,2467.63,1261,2535.2,1212.36Zm74.05-6.39c-48.06,46.21-96.8,108.37-116.53,108.37a7.6,7.6,0,0,1-2.69-.46,6.68,6.68,0,0,1-2.92-1.19c31.51-33.58,75.3-82.15,121.88-109.84A19.8,19.8,0,0,1,2609.25,1206Z" style="fill:#00898d"/><path d="M2383.42,1382.77c-63.3,69-127.15,151.1-171.72,211.09h0c-25.43-63.24-36.74-120.61-36.74-172.62v50.19c0,52,11.31,109.38,36.74,172.62,44.57-60,108.42-142.13,171.72-211.09Z" style="fill:#00898d"/><path d="M2273.36,1611.29v50.19C2767.29,1539,2890.2,1351,2890.2,1201v-50.18C2890.2,1300.79,2767.29,1488.78,2273.36,1611.29Z" style="fill:#00898d"/><path d="M1957.87,1493.06c-25.25-14.31-6-51.85-50.41-77L1716.79,1308c-68.46-38.8-165.43-58-231.45-58-24.47,0-44.69,2.64-57.62,7.91v50.19c12.93-5.27,33.15-7.91,57.62-7.91,66,0,163,19.23,231.45,58l190.67,108.07c44.38,25.15,25.16,62.68,50.41,77,66,37.43,114.46,68.39,185.1,108.44,8.16,4.62,16.48,9.19,24.88,13.71v-50.19c-8.4-4.52-16.72-9.09-24.88-13.71C2072.33,1561.46,2023.9,1530.49,1957.87,1493.06Z" style="fill:#00898d"/><path d="M1098.79,1088.07v50.19c0,165.7,135.34,483.1,912.18,549.21-131.77,30.76-299.74,71.44-428.33,107.6-6.48.06-12.81.32-19.18.32-18.27,0-36.73-2.21-55.9-4.42s-39.13-4.43-60.32-4.43a259.31,259.31,0,0,0-52.37,5.12c-71.65,14.7-147.44,56.85-147.44,87.8v50.19c0-31,75.79-73.1,147.44-87.8a258.59,258.59,0,0,1,52.37-5.12c21.19,0,41.12,2.21,60.32,4.42s37.63,4.43,55.9,4.43c6.37,0,12.7-.27,19.18-.32,154.13-43.35,364.86-93.18,502-124.65v-27.76q12.2.75,24.55,1.43v-50.19C1245.39,1597.29,1098.79,1260.53,1098.79,1088.07Z" style="fill:#00898d"/><path d="M1296.32,2054.12c-146.26,0-272-21.28-346.52-40.09v50.19c74.47,18.81,200.26,40.08,346.52,40.08,263.78,0,594.16-69.18,810.37-346.82V1707.3C1890.48,1984.93,1560.1,2054.12,1296.32,2054.12Z" style="fill:#00898d"/><path d="M2535.2,1163.26c-43.64,42.91-77.89,86.79-90.84,86.79-3.25-.67-4.71-2.41-4.71-5v50.19c0,2.62,1.46,4.36,4.71,5,7.46,0,22-14.56,41.3-35.1v45.56c0,2.23,1.36,3.7,4.37,4.27a7.6,7.6,0,0,0,2.69.46c8.57,0,22.6-11.71,39.66-28.75v38.74c0,2.32,1.45,3.89,4.65,4.58a9.54,9.54,0,0,0,2.76.38c27.92,0,100.35-102.12,159.33-137.56v-50.19c-59,35.45-131.41,137.56-159.33,137.56-.32,0-.63,0-.94-.06,34.71-35.63,79.85-88.55,117.34-111.21a19.29,19.29,0,0,1,.71,5.31V1124a19.34,19.34,0,0,0-.71-5.31c-14.82,9-30.84,22.65-46.94,38.13v-50.09a19.87,19.87,0,0,0-.26-3.21c-18,10.69-35.53,24.48-52.13,39.32v-42a7.25,7.25,0,0,0-.49-2.73c-71.58,49-164.41,125.83-180.6,170a39.85,39.85,0,0,0-3.23,15.86v50.18a39.84,39.84,0,0,1,3.23-15.85C2390.4,1278.47,2467.63,1211.88,2535.2,1163.26Zm74.05-6.39c-48.06,46.21-96.8,108.37-116.53,108.37a7.6,7.6,0,0,1-2.69-.46,6.68,6.68,0,0,1-2.92-1.19c31.51-33.58,75.3-82.15,121.88-109.84A19.9,19.9,0,0,1,2609.25,1156.87Z" style="fill:#00a599"/><path d="M2383.42,1333.68c-63.3,69-127.15,151.09-171.72,211.09h0c-25.43-63.24-36.74-120.62-36.74-172.62v50.18c0,52,11.31,109.38,36.74,172.62,44.57-60,108.42-142.13,171.72-211.09Z" style="fill:#00a599"/><path d="M2273.36,1562.19v50.19c493.93-122.51,616.84-310.5,616.84-460.48v-50.19C2890.2,1251.69,2767.29,1439.68,2273.36,1562.19Z" style="fill:#00a599"/><path d="M1957.87,1444c-25.25-14.31-6-51.85-50.41-77L1716.79,1258.9c-68.46-38.79-165.43-58-231.45-58-24.47,0-44.69,2.64-57.62,7.9V1259c12.93-5.27,33.15-7.91,57.62-7.91,66,0,163,19.23,231.45,58l190.67,108.07c44.38,25.14,25.16,62.68,50.41,77,66,37.43,114.46,68.4,185.1,108.44,8.16,4.62,16.48,9.19,24.88,13.71v-50.19c-8.4-4.52-16.72-9.09-24.88-13.71C2072.33,1512.36,2023.9,1481.39,1957.87,1444Z" style="fill:#00a599"/><path d="M1098.79,1039v50.19c0,165.7,135.34,483.1,912.18,549.21-131.77,30.76-299.74,71.44-428.33,107.6-6.48.06-12.81.33-19.18.33-18.27,0-36.73-2.21-55.9-4.43s-39.13-4.43-60.32-4.43a259.31,259.31,0,0,0-52.37,5.12c-71.65,14.7-147.44,56.85-147.44,87.8v50.19c0-31,75.79-73.1,147.44-87.8a258.59,258.59,0,0,1,52.37-5.12c21.19,0,41.12,2.21,60.32,4.43s37.63,4.42,55.9,4.42c6.37,0,12.7-.26,19.18-.32,154.13-43.34,364.86-93.18,502-124.65v-27.76q12.2.75,24.55,1.43V1595C1245.39,1548.2,1098.79,1211.43,1098.79,1039Z" style="fill:#00a599"/><path d="M1296.32,2005c-146.26,0-272-21.28-346.52-40.09v50.19c74.47,18.81,200.26,40.09,346.52,40.09,263.78,0,594.16-69.19,810.37-346.83V1658.2C1890.48,1935.83,1560.1,2005,1296.32,2005Z" style="fill:#00a599"/><path d="M2535.2,1114.16c-43.64,42.91-77.89,86.8-90.84,86.8-3.25-.68-4.71-2.42-4.71-5v50.19c0,2.62,1.46,4.36,4.71,5,7.46,0,22-14.56,41.3-35.1v45.56c0,2.23,1.36,3.7,4.37,4.27a7.6,7.6,0,0,0,2.69.46c8.57,0,22.6-11.71,39.66-28.75v38.74c0,2.33,1.45,3.9,4.65,4.58a9.54,9.54,0,0,0,2.76.38c27.92,0,100.35-102.11,159.33-137.56v-50.19c-59,35.45-131.41,137.57-159.33,137.57-.32,0-.63,0-.94-.07,34.71-35.63,79.85-88.55,117.34-111.21a19.34,19.34,0,0,1,.71,5.31v-50.19a19.34,19.34,0,0,0-.71-5.31c-14.82,9-30.84,22.65-46.94,38.14v-50.1a19.87,19.87,0,0,0-.26-3.21c-18,10.69-35.53,24.48-52.13,39.33v-42a7.25,7.25,0,0,0-.49-2.73c-71.58,49-164.41,125.83-180.6,170.06a39.77,39.77,0,0,0-3.23,15.85v50.18a39.84,39.84,0,0,1,3.23-15.85C2390.4,1229.37,2467.63,1162.78,2535.2,1114.16Zm74.05-6.39c-48.06,46.21-96.8,108.38-116.53,108.38a7.83,7.83,0,0,1-2.69-.46,6.68,6.68,0,0,1-2.92-1.2c31.51-33.58,75.3-82.14,121.88-109.84A19.9,19.9,0,0,1,2609.25,1107.77Z" style="fill:#00c2a3"/><path d="M2383.42,1284.58c-63.3,69-127.15,151.09-171.72,211.09h0c-25.43-63.24-36.74-120.62-36.74-172.62v50.19c0,52,11.31,109.38,36.74,172.62,44.57-60,108.42-142.14,171.72-211.09Z" style="fill:#00c2a3"/><path d="M2273.36,1513.1v50.18c493.93-122.51,616.84-310.5,616.84-460.48v-50.19C2890.2,1202.6,2767.29,1390.58,2273.36,1513.1Z" style="fill:#00c2a3"/><path d="M1957.87,1394.86c-25.25-14.31-6-51.85-50.41-77L1716.79,1209.8c-68.46-38.79-165.43-58-231.45-58-24.47,0-44.69,2.64-57.62,7.9v50.19c12.93-5.26,33.15-7.91,57.62-7.91,66,0,163,19.24,231.45,58l190.67,108.07c44.38,25.14,25.16,62.68,50.41,77,66,37.43,114.46,68.4,185.1,108.44,8.16,4.62,16.48,9.19,24.88,13.71V1517c-8.4-4.53-16.72-9.1-24.88-13.72C2072.33,1463.26,2023.9,1432.29,1957.87,1394.86Z" style="fill:#00c2a3"/><path d="M1098.79,989.87v50.19c0,165.7,135.34,483.1,912.18,549.21-131.77,30.76-299.74,71.44-428.33,107.6-6.48.06-12.81.33-19.18.33-18.27,0-36.73-2.21-55.9-4.43s-39.13-4.43-60.32-4.43a258.63,258.63,0,0,0-52.37,5.13c-71.65,14.69-147.44,56.84-147.44,87.79v50.19c0-31,75.79-73.1,147.44-87.8a259.31,259.31,0,0,1,52.37-5.12c21.19,0,41.12,2.21,60.32,4.43s37.63,4.42,55.9,4.42c6.37,0,12.7-.26,19.18-.32,154.13-43.34,364.86-93.18,502-124.64v-27.77q12.2.75,24.55,1.43v-50.19C1245.39,1499.1,1098.79,1162.33,1098.79,989.87Z" style="fill:#00c2a3"/><path d="M1296.32,1955.92c-146.26,0-272-21.28-346.52-40.09V1966c74.47,18.81,200.26,40.09,346.52,40.09,263.78,0,594.16-69.19,810.37-346.82V1609.1C1890.48,1886.73,1560.1,1955.92,1296.32,1955.92Z" style="fill:#00c2a3"/><path d="M2535.2,1065.06c-43.64,42.91-77.89,86.8-90.84,86.8-3.25-.68-4.71-2.42-4.71-5V1197c0,2.62,1.46,4.36,4.71,5,7.46,0,22-14.57,41.3-35.11v45.56c0,2.23,1.36,3.7,4.37,4.28a7.83,7.83,0,0,0,2.69.46c8.57,0,22.6-11.72,39.66-28.75v38.74c0,2.32,1.45,3.89,4.65,4.57a9.54,9.54,0,0,0,2.76.39c27.92,0,100.35-102.12,159.33-137.57v-50.19c-59,35.45-131.41,137.57-159.33,137.57-.32,0-.63,0-.94-.07,34.71-35.63,79.85-88.54,117.34-111.21a19.34,19.34,0,0,1,.71,5.31v-50.18a19.36,19.36,0,0,0-.71-5.32c-14.82,9-30.84,22.66-46.94,38.14v-50.1a19.87,19.87,0,0,0-.26-3.21c-18,10.69-35.53,24.49-52.13,39.33v-42a7.25,7.25,0,0,0-.49-2.73c-71.58,49-164.41,125.83-180.6,170.06a39.81,39.81,0,0,0-3.23,15.85v50.19a39.77,39.77,0,0,1,3.23-15.85C2390.4,1180.27,2467.63,1113.68,2535.2,1065.06Zm74.05-6.39c-48.06,46.21-96.8,108.38-116.53,108.38a7.6,7.6,0,0,1-2.69-.46,6.68,6.68,0,0,1-2.92-1.2c31.51-33.57,75.3-82.14,121.88-109.84A19.9,19.9,0,0,1,2609.25,1058.67Z" style="fill:#4edeaa"/><path d="M2383.42,1235.48c-63.3,69-127.15,151.09-171.72,211.09h0C2186.27,1383.33,2175,1326,2175,1274v50.19c0,52,11.31,109.38,36.74,172.62,44.57-60,108.42-142.14,171.72-211.09Z" style="fill:#4edeaa"/><path d="M2273.36,1464v50.19c493.93-122.52,616.84-310.51,616.84-460.49v-50.19C2890.2,1153.5,2767.29,1341.49,2273.36,1464Z" style="fill:#4edeaa"/><path d="M1957.87,1345.76c-25.25-14.31-6-51.85-50.41-77L1716.79,1160.7c-68.46-38.79-165.43-58-231.45-58-24.47,0-44.69,2.64-57.62,7.9v50.19c12.93-5.26,33.15-7.9,57.62-7.9,66,0,163,19.23,231.45,58L1907.46,1319c44.38,25.14,25.16,62.68,50.41,77,66,37.43,114.46,68.4,185.1,108.44,8.16,4.62,16.48,9.19,24.88,13.71v-50.18c-8.4-4.53-16.72-9.1-24.88-13.71C2072.33,1414.16,2023.9,1383.19,1957.87,1345.76Z" style="fill:#4edeaa"/><path d="M1098.79,940.77V991c0,165.71,135.34,483.1,912.18,549.22-131.77,30.76-299.74,71.43-428.33,107.6-6.48,0-12.81.32-19.18.32-18.27,0-36.73-2.21-55.9-4.43s-39.13-4.43-60.32-4.43a258.63,258.63,0,0,0-52.37,5.13c-71.65,14.7-147.44,56.85-147.44,87.79v50.19c0-30.95,75.79-73.1,147.44-87.79a258.63,258.63,0,0,1,52.37-5.13c21.19,0,41.12,2.21,60.32,4.43s37.63,4.43,55.9,4.43c6.37,0,12.7-.27,19.18-.33,154.13-43.34,364.86-93.18,502-124.64v-27.77q12.2.75,24.55,1.43v-50.19C1245.39,1450,1098.79,1113.23,1098.79,940.77Z" style="fill:#4edeaa"/><path d="M1296.32,1906.82c-146.26,0-272-21.27-346.52-40.08v50.18c74.47,18.81,200.26,40.09,346.52,40.09,263.78,0,594.16-69.19,810.37-346.82V1560C1890.48,1837.63,1560.1,1906.82,1296.32,1906.82Z" style="fill:#4edeaa"/><path d="M1370.46,1325.07l-1.55-.86c-68.19-38.22-120.11-79.94-159.27-122.36q-2.51-2.7-4.93-5.42t-4.78-5.42q-5.92-6.78-11.4-13.57c-1.48-1.82-2.91-3.63-4.33-5.43s-2.83-3.63-4.19-5.44-2.74-3.63-4.07-5.44-2.67-3.63-4-5.43c-3.87-5.42-7.57-10.86-11.1-16.27-1.16-1.81-2.31-3.6-3.43-5.4-.57-.9-1.13-1.81-1.69-2.71-1.12-1.8-2.21-3.61-3.28-5.4-.73-1.22-1.45-2.45-2.17-3.68-.86-1.45-1.7-2.93-2.53-4.38-1-1.79-2-3.58-3-5.39-.8-1.47-1.59-2.92-2.38-4.4-32.84-61.79-43.61-120.57-43.61-167.28v246.56c0,98.58,47.91,250.86,250.3,372q11.25-3.55,22.92-6.89V1325.93C1371.49,1325.65,1371,1325.37,1370.46,1325.07Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#a)"/><path d="M1510.68,1890.6a1356.13,1356.13,0,0,1-168,15.5c-15.65.49-31.14.72-46.39.72q-18.87,0-37.25-.47c-.33,0-.65,0-1,0-3.58-.07-7.14-.18-10.68-.3-125.2-4-231.59-22.62-297.63-39.3v246.58c74.48,18.82,200.27,40.09,346.52,40.09,86.8,0,180.8-7.49,275.6-27.44V1879.38Q1541.22,1885.85,1510.68,1890.6Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#b)"/><path d="M2095.48,1574.05a6.37,6.37,0,0,1-.59.74q-7.63,9.39-15.49,18.45-5.83,6.78-11.85,13.41a8.12,8.12,0,0,1-.63.7q-11.31,12.56-23,24.45c-2.24,2.31-4.52,4.59-6.8,6.85-.23.25-.47.48-.7.69q-23.91,23.78-49.06,44.92l-1.16,1c-4.54,3.81-9.12,7.58-13.71,11.24-.63.53-1.28,1-1.91,1.55q-20,16-40.62,30.45-33.79,23.84-69,43.81c-1.14.65-2.26,1.28-3.4,1.91a906.92,906.92,0,0,1-96.18,46.89v246.58c127.29-53.19,248-136,345.39-261.1V1560C2103,1564.74,2099.27,1569.42,2095.48,1574.05Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#c)"/><path d="M1651.86,1628.85h0l-2.08.56c-3.6,1-7.18,1.91-10.74,2.88-4.31,1.16-8.61,2.31-12.87,3.47l-12.67,3.45-1.3.36c-2.51.7-5,1.38-7.51,2.06q-11.18,3.09-22,6.14c-6.49,0-12.82.33-19.18.33s-12.75-.28-19.19-.71c-12-.83-24.23-2.27-36.72-3.72-19.2-2.21-39.12-4.42-60.32-4.42a258.42,258.42,0,0,0-52.36,5.12,350.34,350.34,0,0,0-50,14.36c-2.16.79-4.32,1.6-6.44,2.44s-4.26,1.66-6.35,2.54c-29.33,12.07-54.92,27.18-70.07,42.16-.54.52-1.07,1.07-1.59,1.59-8.23,8.54-13,17-13,24.71a17.9,17.9,0,0,0,2.47,9.12,66.14,66.14,0,0,0,11.31,14.45l.54.54c10,9.49,22.87,16.39,37.79,21.11.41.16.83.28,1.25.41,17.78,5.47,38.33,7.89,60,7.89,58.31,0,124.43-17.61,165.66-40.62.54-.29,1.08-.59,1.61-.91a155.23,155.23,0,0,0,14.8-9.5c14.11-10.31,24.53-23.6,37.86-36.67.37-.37.75-.75,1.14-1.1,2.75-2.67,5.63-5.32,8.69-7.93,15.28-4.38,31.27-8.87,47.86-13.41q9.6-2.64,19.48-5.3v-43C1655.84,1627.78,1653.84,1628.33,1651.86,1628.85Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#d)"/><path d="M2084.63,1495.36q-22.34-1.35-44-3c-.71,0-1.39-.12-2.09-.15q-46.59-3.56-90.18-8.24c-.25,0-.48-.06-.71-.09q-10.14-1.08-20.14-2.25c-.34,0-.67-.07-1-.1q-54.13-6.27-103.76-14.21-59.7-9.51-113.17-21.25v50.19q13,2.84,26.39,5.56c1.65,0,3.3-.07,4.94-.07h0q16.07-.32,32.56-.3,55.24,0,115.14,3.21,25.06,1.33,51,3.33a1.56,1.56,0,0,1,.3,0q24.36,1.83,49.49,4.26l2.22.21q45.27,4.4,93,10.64v42l22.06-5.08v183.22c.84.06,1.66.09,2.51.14V1496.79Q2096.81,1496.11,2084.63,1495.36Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#e)"/><path d="M2890.11,1010.33v0c0,1.07-.05,2.14-.11,3.21,0,.54,0,1.07-.05,1.59s0,1.09-.09,1.62c-.08,2.12-.22,4.26-.38,6.42v.14c-.18,2.5-.41,5-.67,7.55-.19,2-.42,4-.66,6,0,.08,0,.17,0,.24-.26,2.12-.54,4.24-.86,6.37,0,.17-.05.33-.09.5q-.47,3.13-1,6.26l-.11.58c-.4,2.28-.82,4.56-1.3,6.84-.31,1.55-.65,3.07-1,4.61-.7,3.09-1.44,6.19-2.24,9.3-.3,1.15-.62,2.33-.93,3.49-1,3.49-2,7-3.12,10.52q-1.5,4.68-3.18,9.4h0a311.49,311.49,0,0,1-40.43,76.32v0c-1.85,2.56-3.72,5.12-5.65,7.66v0c-1.46,1.91-2.93,3.84-4.44,5.76q-3.39,4.32-7,8.63t-7.4,8.65a486.34,486.34,0,0,1-60.45,57.18c-3.12,2.52-6.33,5-9.59,7.54s-6.57,5-10,7.52-6.84,5-10.36,7.49-7.1,5-10.75,7.45-7.35,5-11.14,7.42-7.62,4.93-11.53,7.38q-8.82,5.51-18.08,11l-1.46.86q-14.78,8.67-30.77,17.25-13.42,7.19-27.71,14.27c-2.37,1.2-4.77,2.37-7.19,3.55-4.84,2.35-9.75,4.68-14.75,7-2.49,1.17-5,2.33-7.52,3.49q-7.6,3.46-15.41,6.94c-.81.37-1.63.72-2.44,1.07l-3.66,1.61q-8.42,3.66-17.12,7.3c-.66.3-1.33.56-2,.84-3.28,1.37-6.57,2.74-9.9,4.07v246.58c284-115.61,362.61-259.84,362.61-379.78V1004C2890.2,1006.07,2890.16,1008.19,2890.11,1010.33Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#f)"/><path d="M2505.12,1392.21q-8.65,3.35-17.51,6.67l-2,.72q-7.92,2.94-16.06,5.85-13.68,4.92-27.92,9.75-9.49,3.21-19.23,6.39-4.87,1.59-9.82,3.17-9.87,3.15-20,6.28l-9.21,2.8v-2l-2.47,2.7q-27,8.14-55.82,16l-1.17.32q-24,6.53-49.36,12.82l-1.07.26-.18,0v246.58c99-24.55,183-51.73,254.23-80.71V1383.29Q2516.56,1387.8,2505.12,1392.21Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#g)"/><path d="M1716.79,1160.7c-68.45-38.79-165.42-58-231.44-58-24.48,0-44.68,2.65-57.62,7.91L1501,1152.1l2.08,1.2,119.8,67.89,3.82,2.16,183.69,104.11v-113.7C1781.64,1197.45,1749.15,1179.06,1716.79,1160.7Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#h)"/><path d="M2556.38,1000c-54.27,37.16-120.77,90.31-156.8,133.13v171c13.26-15.62,26.69-31,40.07-45.73V1146.83a15.23,15.23,0,0,1,1.86-6.37c.33-.67.7-1.37,1.12-2.1,18.25-32.13,114.24-111,114.24-135.64A7.16,7.16,0,0,0,2556.38,1000Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#i)"/><path d="M2609.23,1007.77a18.59,18.59,0,0,0-.23-2.4c-3.57,2.12-7.14,4.37-10.66,6.72-1.17.78-2.35,1.59-3.52,2.4q-4.61,3.15-9.12,6.52c-.84.61-1.67,1.25-2.51,1.88l-2.33,1.79c-1.16.87-2.3,1.78-3.46,2.68s-2.19,1.75-3.28,2.63c-5.85,4.73-11.6,9.66-17.25,14.69-6,5.33-11.78,10.79-17.47,16.28l-4.2,4.1c-13.65,13.43-26.36,26.93-37.79,39.16-1.14,1.21-2.28,2.42-3.39,3.63-.57.59-1.14,1.19-1.68,1.78-.37.39-.72.78-1.07,1.14s-.7.74-1.05,1.11v40.5a128.37,128.37,0,0,1,10-12c1.15-1.26,2.36-2.56,3.61-3.88h0c14-14.79,34.12-33.46,53-52.58,27-27.26,51.52-55.37,52.38-74.29v-1C2609.25,1008.32,2609.25,1008,2609.23,1007.77Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#j)"/><path d="M2656.87,1025a18.31,18.31,0,0,0-.37-3.17c-.08-.44-.19-.86-.31-1.28a217.86,217.86,0,0,0-28.92,21.62q-2.34,2-4.68,4.12-6.63,5.91-13.34,12.38v0c-3,2.87-6,5.84-9,8.83s-5.87,5.91-8.82,8.91c-1.54,1.6-3.1,3.19-4.63,4.79s-2.85,3-4.29,4.47c-8.77,9.17-17.38,18.4-25.62,27.16l-4.52,4.81c-.9.93-1.78,1.86-2.63,2.77-.5.51-1,1-1.44,1.52-.86.92-1.72,1.81-2.6,2.7-1.37,1.44-2.72,2.86-4.07,4.25v32.47c2.88-3.33,6.33-7,10.21-10.92a0,0,0,0,0,0,0c5.78-5.84,12.52-12.26,19.72-19.06l8-7.47c9.73-9.12,20-18.76,29.74-28.48,25.74-25.62,48-51.67,47.64-70C2656.89,1025.31,2656.87,1025.15,2656.87,1025Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#k)"/><path d="M2656.91,1077.49c-16.22,14.94-32.46,31.79-47.66,47.52-19.78,20.48-37.83,39-51.85,49.12l-.53.37V1192l.53-.47v19c-.2.19-.37.38-.53.56v5c.18-.08.35-.21.53-.31,21.2-13.34,37-31.76,51.85-49.94,7.38-9.07,14.5-18.1,21.88-26.39,1.46-1.63,2.91-3.25,4.37-4.84q1.71-1.92,3.42-3.79c6.24-6.89,12.29-13.48,18-19.9,21.18-23.74,37.72-44.75,42.21-66.44C2685.53,1052.59,2671.22,1064.31,2656.91,1077.49Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#l)"/><path d="M2819.46,807.12c93.26,118.57,220.83,466.65-546.1,656.88,43.78-58.9,107.11-140.73,169-208.61a167.5,167.5,0,0,1,16.9-8.74c19.54-8.41,63.52-13.54,84.65-23.53,40-18.87,62-55.45,87.18-83.71,32.59-36.37,61.77-65,68-95-59,35.45-131.41,137.57-159.33,137.57a9.54,9.54,0,0,1-2.76-.39c-34.19-7.31,131.93-115.66,119.16-161.08-59.07,35.71-137.13,146.52-163.47,146.52a7.6,7.6,0,0,1-2.69-.46c-32.43-6.18,126.47-116.52,119-161.23-76.2,45.31-145,146.5-164.63,146.5-33.43-7,122.3-126.5,112-151.86-71.58,49-164.41,125.83-180.6,170.06-10.43,24.44,7.79,45.5,7.65,65.42-63.3,69-127.15,151.09-171.72,211.09C2025.62,983.83,2595.66,835.1,2819.46,807.12ZM1102.77,893.58c-26.43,147.86,54.43,551.64,1006.41,603.21l-681.46-386.21c12.93-5.26,33.15-7.9,57.62-7.9,66,0,163,19.23,231.45,58l190.67,108.07c44.38,25.14,25.16,62.68,50.41,77,66,37.43,114.46,68.4,185.1,108.45,8.16,4.61,16.48,9.18,24.87,13.71-80.07-493.2-677.18-576.57-982.11-576.58C1154.78,891.34,1126.86,892.2,1102.77,893.58Zm-153,973.16c74.47,18.81,200.26,40.08,346.52,40.08,263.78,0,594.16-69.19,810.37-346.82-143.5,33-365.52,85.67-516.19,129-18.51,15.74-30.3,33-47.69,45.68-38.09,27.89-115.24,51-182.07,51-48.92,0-92.31-12.39-110.84-44.41-18.05-31.13,66-80.71,145-96.91a258.63,258.63,0,0,1,52.37-5.13c21.19,0,41.12,2.21,60.32,4.43s37.63,4.43,55.9,4.43c6.37,0,12.7-.27,19.18-.32,154.13-43.35,364.86-93.19,502-124.65-114.15-15-217.6-21.67-311.13-21.67C1193.74,1501.43,992.42,1757.23,949.8,1866.74Z" style="fill:url(#m)"/></g></svg>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is related to the SVG path order, try to change path order.

[Sample Code](https://codepen.io/Dillion121/pen/oNgzgEY) as below:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 3840 2160">
    <defs>

        <linearGradient id="a" x1="1098.8" y1="1250.05" x2="1372.02" y2="1250.05" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="gray" />
            <stop offset="0.1" style="stop-color:#8f8f8f;stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="0.52" style="stop-color:#cbcbcb; stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="0.84" style="stop-color:#f1f1f1; stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#fff; stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>

        <linearGradient id="b" x1="949.29" y1="2007.84" x2="1561.63" y2="2015.91" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="gray" />
            <stop offset="0.15" stop-color="#9b9b9b" />
            <stop offset="0.41" stop-color="#c6c6c6" />
            <stop offset="0.66" stop-color="#e5e5e5" />
            <stop offset="0.86" stop-color="#f8f8f8" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" />
        </linearGradient>

        <linearGradient id="c" x1="2167.21" y1="1714.96" x2="1710.54" y2="1908.61" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#999" />
            <stop offset="0.18" stop-color="#b9b9b9" />
            <stop offset="0.4" stop-color="#d8d8d8" />
            <stop offset="0.61" stop-color="#ededed" />
            <stop offset="0.81" stop-color="#fbfbfb" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" />
        </linearGradient>

        <linearGradient id="d" x1="1647.4" y1="1612.59" x2="1275.61" y2="1770.24" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" />
            <stop offset="0.34" stop-color="#fdfdfd" />
            <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="#f5f5f5" />
            <stop offset="0.63" stop-color="#e8e8e8" />
            <stop offset="0.74" stop-color="#d5d5d5" />
            <stop offset="0.84" stop-color="#bdbdbd" />
            <stop offset="0.92" stop-color="#a0a0a0" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="gray" />
        </linearGradient>

        <linearGradient id="e" x1="1709.57" y1="1594.73" x2="2109.2" y2="1594.73" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" />
            <stop offset="0.52" stop-color="#f4f4f4" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#e6e6e6" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="f" x1="2527.59" y1="1316.91" x2="2890.2" y2="1316.91" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" />
            <stop offset="0.19" stop-color="#fbfbfb" />
            <stop offset="0.39" stop-color="#ededed" />
            <stop offset="0.6" stop-color="#d8d8d8" />
            <stop offset="0.82" stop-color="#b9b9b9" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#999" />
        </linearGradient>

        <linearGradient id="g" x1="2273.36" y1="1546.94" x2="2527.59" y2="1546.94" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#999" />
            <stop offset="0.24" stop-color="#b9b9b9" />
            <stop offset="0.57" stop-color="#dfdfdf" />
            <stop offset="0.83" stop-color="#f6f6f6" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" />
        </linearGradient>

        <linearGradient id="h" x1="1427.73" y1="1215.06" x2="1810.4" y2="1215.06" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="gray" />
            <stop offset="0.05" stop-color="#8f8f8f" />
            <stop offset="0.17" stop-color="#b1b1b1" />
            <stop offset="0.29" stop-color="#cecece" />
            <stop offset="0.43" stop-color="#e3e3e3" />
            <stop offset="0.58" stop-color="#f3f3f3" />
            <stop offset="0.75" stop-color="#fcfcfc" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" />
        </linearGradient>

        <linearGradient id="i" x1="2399.58" y1="1152.08" x2="2556.87" y2="1152.08" xlink:href="#f" />

        <linearGradient id="j" x1="2490.22" y1="1078.88" x2="2609.25" y2="1078.88" xlink:href="#f" />

        <linearGradient id="k" x1="2558.22" y1="1091.26" x2="2627.37" y2="1090.73" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" />
            <stop offset="0.26" stop-color="#f9f9f9" />
            <stop offset="0.59" stop-color="#e9e9e9" />
            <stop offset="0.96" stop-color="#cfcfcf" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#ccc" />
        </linearGradient>

        <linearGradient id="l" x1="2577.37" y1="1130.63" x2="2662.72" y2="1129.98" xlink:href="#k" />

        <linearGradient id="m" x1="2242.34" y1="1912.74" x2="1518.04" y2="742.98" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" />
            <stop offset="0.1" stop-color="#f0fef5" />
            <stop offset="0.52" stop-color="#b6fcd0" />
            <stop offset="0.83" stop-color="#92fbb9" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#84fab0" />
        </linearGradient>

    </defs>

    <title>svg</title>

    <path d="M1370.46,1325.07l-1.55-.86c-68.19-38.22-120.11-79.94-159.27-122.36q-2.51-2.7-4.93-5.42t-4.78-5.42q-5.92-6.78-11.4-13.57c-1.48-1.82-2.91-3.63-4.33-5.43s-2.83-3.63-4.19-5.44-2.74-3.63-4.07-5.44-2.67-3.63-4-5.43c-3.87-5.42-7.57-10.86-11.1-16.27-1.16-1.81-2.31-3.6-3.43-5.4-.57-.9-1.13-1.81-1.69-2.71-1.12-1.8-2.21-3.61-3.28-5.4-.73-1.22-1.45-2.45-2.17-3.68-.86-1.45-1.7-2.93-2.53-4.38-1-1.79-2-3.58-3-5.39-.8-1.47-1.59-2.92-2.38-4.4-32.84-61.79-43.61-120.57-43.61-167.28v246.56c0,98.58,47.91,250.86,250.3,372q11.25-3.55,22.92-6.89V1325.93C1371.49,1325.65,1371,1325.37,1370.46,1325.07Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#a)" />
    <path d="M1510.68,1890.6a1356.13,1356.13,0,0,1-168,15.5c-15.65.49-31.14.72-46.39.72q-18.87,0-37.25-.47c-.33,0-.65,0-1,0-3.58-.07-7.14-.18-10.68-.3-125.2-4-231.59-22.62-297.63-39.3v246.58c74.48,18.82,200.27,40.09,346.52,40.09,86.8,0,180.8-7.49,275.6-27.44V1879.38Q1541.22,1885.85,1510.68,1890.6Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#b)" />
    <path d="M2095.48,1574.05a6.37,6.37,0,0,1-.59.74q-7.63,9.39-15.49,18.45-5.83,6.78-11.85,13.41a8.12,8.12,0,0,1-.63.7q-11.31,12.56-23,24.45c-2.24,2.31-4.52,4.59-6.8,6.85-.23.25-.47.48-.7.69q-23.91,23.78-49.06,44.92l-1.16,1c-4.54,3.81-9.12,7.58-13.71,11.24-.63.53-1.28,1-1.91,1.55q-20,16-40.62,30.45-33.79,23.84-69,43.81c-1.14.65-2.26,1.28-3.4,1.91a906.92,906.92,0,0,1-96.18,46.89v246.58c127.29-53.19,248-136,345.39-261.1V1560C2103,1564.74,2099.27,1569.42,2095.48,1574.05Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#c)" />
    <path d="M1651.86,1628.85h0l-2.08.56c-3.6,1-7.18,1.91-10.74,2.88-4.31,1.16-8.61,2.31-12.87,3.47l-12.67,3.45-1.3.36c-2.51.7-5,1.38-7.51,2.06q-11.18,3.09-22,6.14c-6.49,0-12.82.33-19.18.33s-12.75-.28-19.19-.71c-12-.83-24.23-2.27-36.72-3.72-19.2-2.21-39.12-4.42-60.32-4.42a258.42,258.42,0,0,0-52.36,5.12,350.34,350.34,0,0,0-50,14.36c-2.16.79-4.32,1.6-6.44,2.44s-4.26,1.66-6.35,2.54c-29.33,12.07-54.92,27.18-70.07,42.16-.54.52-1.07,1.07-1.59,1.59-8.23,8.54-13,17-13,24.71a17.9,17.9,0,0,0,2.47,9.12,66.14,66.14,0,0,0,11.31,14.45l.54.54c10,9.49,22.87,16.39,37.79,21.11.41.16.83.28,1.25.41,17.78,5.47,38.33,7.89,60,7.89,58.31,0,124.43-17.61,165.66-40.62.54-.29,1.08-.59,1.61-.91a155.23,155.23,0,0,0,14.8-9.5c14.11-10.31,24.53-23.6,37.86-36.67.37-.37.75-.75,1.14-1.1,2.75-2.67,5.63-5.32,8.69-7.93,15.28-4.38,31.27-8.87,47.86-13.41q9.6-2.64,19.48-5.3v-43C1655.84,1627.78,1653.84,1628.33,1651.86,1628.85Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#d)" />
    <path d="M2084.63,1495.36q-22.34-1.35-44-3c-.71,0-1.39-.12-2.09-.15q-46.59-3.56-90.18-8.24c-.25,0-.48-.06-.71-.09q-10.14-1.08-20.14-2.25c-.34,0-.67-.07-1-.1q-54.13-6.27-103.76-14.21-59.7-9.51-113.17-21.25v50.19q13,2.84,26.39,5.56c1.65,0,3.3-.07,4.94-.07h0q16.07-.32,32.56-.3,55.24,0,115.14,3.21,25.06,1.33,51,3.33a1.56,1.56,0,0,1,.3,0q24.36,1.83,49.49,4.26l2.22.21q45.27,4.4,93,10.64v42l22.06-5.08v183.22c.84.06,1.66.09,2.51.14V1496.79Q2096.81,1496.11,2084.63,1495.36Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#e)" />
    <path d="M2890.11,1010.33v0c0,1.07-.05,2.14-.11,3.21,0,.54,0,1.07-.05,1.59s0,1.09-.09,1.62c-.08,2.12-.22,4.26-.38,6.42v.14c-.18,2.5-.41,5-.67,7.55-.19,2-.42,4-.66,6,0,.08,0,.17,0,.24-.26,2.12-.54,4.24-.86,6.37,0,.17-.05.33-.09.5q-.47,3.13-1,6.26l-.11.58c-.4,2.28-.82,4.56-1.3,6.84-.31,1.55-.65,3.07-1,4.61-.7,3.09-1.44,6.19-2.24,9.3-.3,1.15-.62,2.33-.93,3.49-1,3.49-2,7-3.12,10.52q-1.5,4.68-3.18,9.4h0a311.49,311.49,0,0,1-40.43,76.32v0c-1.85,2.56-3.72,5.12-5.65,7.66v0c-1.46,1.91-2.93,3.84-4.44,5.76q-3.39,4.32-7,8.63t-7.4,8.65a486.34,486.34,0,0,1-60.45,57.18c-3.12,2.52-6.33,5-9.59,7.54s-6.57,5-10,7.52-6.84,5-10.36,7.49-7.1,5-10.75,7.45-7.35,5-11.14,7.42-7.62,4.93-11.53,7.38q-8.82,5.51-18.08,11l-1.46.86q-14.78,8.67-30.77,17.25-13.42,7.19-27.71,14.27c-2.37,1.2-4.77,2.37-7.19,3.55-4.84,2.35-9.75,4.68-14.75,7-2.49,1.17-5,2.33-7.52,3.49q-7.6,3.46-15.41,6.94c-.81.37-1.63.72-2.44,1.07l-3.66,1.61q-8.42,3.66-17.12,7.3c-.66.3-1.33.56-2,.84-3.28,1.37-6.57,2.74-9.9,4.07v246.58c284-115.61,362.61-259.84,362.61-379.78V1004C2890.2,1006.07,2890.16,1008.19,2890.11,1010.33Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#f)" />
    <path d="M2505.12,1392.21q-8.65,3.35-17.51,6.67l-2,.72q-7.92,2.94-16.06,5.85-13.68,4.92-27.92,9.75-9.49,3.21-19.23,6.39-4.87,1.59-9.82,3.17-9.87,3.15-20,6.28l-9.21,2.8v-2l-2.47,2.7q-27,8.14-55.82,16l-1.17.32q-24,6.53-49.36,12.82l-1.07.26-.18,0v246.58c99-24.55,183-51.73,254.23-80.71V1383.29Q2516.56,1387.8,2505.12,1392.21Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#g)" />
    <path d="M1716.79,1160.7c-68.45-38.79-165.42-58-231.44-58-24.48,0-44.68,2.65-57.62,7.91L1501,1152.1l2.08,1.2,119.8,67.89,3.82,2.16,183.69,104.11v-113.7C1781.64,1197.45,1749.15,1179.06,1716.79,1160.7Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#h)" />
    <path d="M2556.38,1000c-54.27,37.16-120.77,90.31-156.8,133.13v171c13.26-15.62,26.69-31,40.07-45.73V1146.83a15.23,15.23,0,0,1,1.86-6.37c.33-.67.7-1.37,1.12-2.1,18.25-32.13,114.24-111,114.24-135.64A7.16,7.16,0,0,0,2556.38,1000Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#i)" />
    <path d="M2609.23,1007.77a18.59,18.59,0,0,0-.23-2.4c-3.57,2.12-7.14,4.37-10.66,6.72-1.17.78-2.35,1.59-3.52,2.4q-4.61,3.15-9.12,6.52c-.84.61-1.67,1.25-2.51,1.88l-2.33,1.79c-1.16.87-2.3,1.78-3.46,2.68s-2.19,1.75-3.28,2.63c-5.85,4.73-11.6,9.66-17.25,14.69-6,5.33-11.78,10.79-17.47,16.28l-4.2,4.1c-13.65,13.43-26.36,26.93-37.79,39.16-1.14,1.21-2.28,2.42-3.39,3.63-.57.59-1.14,1.19-1.68,1.78-.37.39-.72.78-1.07,1.14s-.7.74-1.05,1.11v40.5a128.37,128.37,0,0,1,10-12c1.15-1.26,2.36-2.56,3.61-3.88h0c14-14.79,34.12-33.46,53-52.58,27-27.26,51.52-55.37,52.38-74.29v-1C2609.25,1008.32,2609.25,1008,2609.23,1007.77Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#j)" />
    <path d="M2656.87,1025a18.31,18.31,0,0,0-.37-3.17c-.08-.44-.19-.86-.31-1.28a217.86,217.86,0,0,0-28.92,21.62q-2.34,2-4.68,4.12-6.63,5.91-13.34,12.38v0c-3,2.87-6,5.84-9,8.83s-5.87,5.91-8.82,8.91c-1.54,1.6-3.1,3.19-4.63,4.79s-2.85,3-4.29,4.47c-8.77,9.17-17.38,18.4-25.62,27.16l-4.52,4.81c-.9.93-1.78,1.86-2.63,2.77-.5.51-1,1-1.44,1.52-.86.92-1.72,1.81-2.6,2.7-1.37,1.44-2.72,2.86-4.07,4.25v32.47c2.88-3.33,6.33-7,10.21-10.92a0,0,0,0,0,0,0c5.78-5.84,12.52-12.26,19.72-19.06l8-7.47c9.73-9.12,20-18.76,29.74-28.48,25.74-25.62,48-51.67,47.64-70C2656.89,1025.31,2656.87,1025.15,2656.87,1025Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#k)" />
    <path d="M2656.91,1077.49c-16.22,14.94-32.46,31.79-47.66,47.52-19.78,20.48-37.83,39-51.85,49.12l-.53.37V1192l.53-.47v19c-.2.19-.37.38-.53.56v5c.18-.08.35-.21.53-.31,21.2-13.34,37-31.76,51.85-49.94,7.38-9.07,14.5-18.1,21.88-26.39,1.46-1.63,2.91-3.25,4.37-4.84q1.71-1.92,3.42-3.79c6.24-6.89,12.29-13.48,18-19.9,21.18-23.74,37.72-44.75,42.21-66.44C2685.53,1052.59,2671.22,1064.31,2656.91,1077.49Z" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply;fill:url(#l)" />


    <path d="M2535.2,1261.46c-43.64,42.91-77.89,86.79-90.84,86.79-3.25-.67-4.71-2.42-4.71-5v50.19c0,2.61,1.46,4.35,4.71,5,7.46,0,22-14.56,41.3-35.11v45.56c0,2.24,1.36,3.71,4.37,4.28a7.6,7.6,0,0,0,2.69.46c8.57,0,22.6-11.72,39.66-28.75v38.74c0,2.32,1.45,3.89,4.65,4.58a9.9,9.9,0,0,0,2.76.38c27.92,0,100.35-102.12,159.33-137.56v-50.19c-59,35.44-131.41,137.56-159.33,137.56-.32,0-.63,0-.94-.06,34.71-35.64,79.85-88.55,117.34-111.22a19.41,19.41,0,0,1,.71,5.32v-50.19a19.29,19.29,0,0,0-.71-5.31c-14.82,9-30.84,22.65-46.94,38.13V1205a19.68,19.68,0,0,0-.26-3.21c-18,10.68-35.53,24.48-52.13,39.32v-42a7.16,7.16,0,0,0-.49-2.72c-71.58,49-164.41,125.82-180.6,170a39.84,39.84,0,0,0-3.23,15.85v50.19a39.81,39.81,0,0,1,3.23-15.85C2390.4,1376.67,2467.63,1310.08,2535.2,1261.46Zm74.05-6.4c-48.06,46.22-96.8,108.38-116.53,108.38a7.6,7.6,0,0,1-2.69-.46,6.81,6.81,0,0,1-2.92-1.19c31.51-33.58,75.3-82.15,121.88-109.84A19.67,19.67,0,0,1,2609.25,1255.06Z" style="fill:#006e7e" />
    <path d="M2383.42,1431.87c-63.3,69-127.15,151.09-171.72,211.09h0c-25.43-63.24-36.74-120.61-36.74-172.62v50.19c0,52,11.31,109.38,36.74,172.62,44.57-60,108.42-142.14,171.72-211.09Z" style="fill:#006e7e" />
    <path d="M2273.36,1660.39v50.19c493.93-122.51,616.84-310.5,616.84-460.49V1199.9C2890.2,1349.89,2767.29,1537.88,2273.36,1660.39Z" style="fill:#006e7e" />
    <path d="M1957.87,1542.16c-25.25-14.32-6-51.85-50.41-77l-190.67-108.07c-68.46-38.79-165.43-58-231.45-58-24.47,0-44.69,2.64-57.62,7.91v50.19c12.93-5.27,33.15-7.91,57.62-7.91,66,0,163,19.23,231.45,58l190.67,108.07c44.38,25.15,25.16,62.68,50.41,77,66,37.42,114.46,68.39,185.1,108.44,8.16,4.62,16.48,9.19,24.88,13.71v-50.19c-8.4-4.52-16.72-9.09-24.88-13.71C2072.33,1610.55,2023.9,1579.59,1957.87,1542.16Z" style="fill:#006e7e" />
    <path d="M1098.79,1137.17v50.19c0,165.7,135.34,483.1,912.18,549.21-131.77,30.76-299.74,71.44-428.33,107.6-6.48,0-12.81.32-19.18.32-18.27,0-36.73-2.21-55.9-4.43s-39.13-4.42-60.32-4.42a258.59,258.59,0,0,0-52.37,5.12c-71.65,14.7-147.44,56.85-147.44,87.8v50.18c0-30.94,75.79-73.09,147.44-87.79a258.59,258.59,0,0,1,52.37-5.12c21.19,0,41.12,2.21,60.32,4.42s37.63,4.43,55.9,4.43c6.37,0,12.7-.27,19.18-.32,154.13-43.35,364.86-93.18,502-124.65V1742q12.2.75,24.55,1.43v-50.19C1245.39,1646.39,1098.79,1309.63,1098.79,1137.17Z" style="fill:#006e7e" />
    <path d="M1296.32,2103.21c-146.26,0-272-21.27-346.52-40.08v50.19c74.47,18.81,200.26,40.08,346.52,40.08,263.78,0,594.16-69.19,810.37-346.82v-50.19C1890.48,2034,1560.1,2103.21,1296.32,2103.21Z" style="fill:#006e7e" />

    <path d="M2535.2,1212.36c-43.64,42.91-77.89,86.79-90.84,86.79-3.25-.67-4.71-2.41-4.71-5v50.19c0,2.61,1.46,4.35,4.71,5,7.46,0,22-14.56,41.3-35.1v45.55c0,2.24,1.36,3.71,4.37,4.28a7.6,7.6,0,0,0,2.69.46c8.57,0,22.6-11.71,39.66-28.75v38.74c0,2.32,1.45,3.89,4.65,4.58a9.54,9.54,0,0,0,2.76.38c27.92,0,100.35-102.12,159.33-137.56v-50.19c-59,35.44-131.41,137.56-159.33,137.56-.32,0-.63,0-.94-.06,34.71-35.64,79.85-88.55,117.34-111.22a19.41,19.41,0,0,1,.71,5.32v-50.19a19.29,19.29,0,0,0-.71-5.31c-14.82,9-30.84,22.65-46.94,38.13v-50.09a19.87,19.87,0,0,0-.26-3.21c-18,10.69-35.53,24.48-52.13,39.32v-42a7.18,7.18,0,0,0-.49-2.73c-71.58,49-164.41,125.82-180.6,170a39.84,39.84,0,0,0-3.23,15.85v50.19a39.81,39.81,0,0,1,3.23-15.85C2390.4,1327.57,2467.63,1261,2535.2,1212.36Zm74.05-6.39c-48.06,46.21-96.8,108.37-116.53,108.37a7.6,7.6,0,0,1-2.69-.46,6.68,6.68,0,0,1-2.92-1.19c31.51-33.58,75.3-82.15,121.88-109.84A19.8,19.8,0,0,1,2609.25,1206Z" style="fill:#00898d" />
    <path d="M2383.42,1382.77c-63.3,69-127.15,151.1-171.72,211.09h0c-25.43-63.24-36.74-120.61-36.74-172.62v50.19c0,52,11.31,109.38,36.74,172.62,44.57-60,108.42-142.13,171.72-211.09Z" style="fill:#00898d" />
    <path d="M2273.36,1611.29v50.19C2767.29,1539,2890.2,1351,2890.2,1201v-50.18C2890.2,1300.79,2767.29,1488.78,2273.36,1611.29Z" style="fill:#00898d" />
    <path d="M1957.87,1493.06c-25.25-14.31-6-51.85-50.41-77L1716.79,1308c-68.46-38.8-165.43-58-231.45-58-24.47,0-44.69,2.64-57.62,7.91v50.19c12.93-5.27,33.15-7.91,57.62-7.91,66,0,163,19.23,231.45,58l190.67,108.07c44.38,25.15,25.16,62.68,50.41,77,66,37.43,114.46,68.39,185.1,108.44,8.16,4.62,16.48,9.19,24.88,13.71v-50.19c-8.4-4.52-16.72-9.09-24.88-13.71C2072.33,1561.46,2023.9,1530.49,1957.87,1493.06Z" style="fill:#00898d" />
    <path d="M1098.79,1088.07v50.19c0,165.7,135.34,483.1,912.18,549.21-131.77,30.76-299.74,71.44-428.33,107.6-6.48.06-12.81.32-19.18.32-18.27,0-36.73-2.21-55.9-4.42s-39.13-4.43-60.32-4.43a259.31,259.31,0,0,0-52.37,5.12c-71.65,14.7-147.44,56.85-147.44,87.8v50.19c0-31,75.79-73.1,147.44-87.8a258.59,258.59,0,0,1,52.37-5.12c21.19,0,41.12,2.21,60.32,4.42s37.63,4.43,55.9,4.43c6.37,0,12.7-.27,19.18-.32,154.13-43.35,364.86-93.18,502-124.65v-27.76q12.2.75,24.55,1.43v-50.19C1245.39,1597.29,1098.79,1260.53,1098.79,1088.07Z" style="fill:#00898d" />
    <path d="M1296.32,2054.12c-146.26,0-272-21.28-346.52-40.09v50.19c74.47,18.81,200.26,40.08,346.52,40.08,263.78,0,594.16-69.18,810.37-346.82V1707.3C1890.48,1984.93,1560.1,2054.12,1296.32,2054.12Z" style="fill:#00898d" />

    <path d="M2535.2,1163.26c-43.64,42.91-77.89,86.79-90.84,86.79-3.25-.67-4.71-2.41-4.71-5v50.19c0,2.62,1.46,4.36,4.71,5,7.46,0,22-14.56,41.3-35.1v45.56c0,2.23,1.36,3.7,4.37,4.27a7.6,7.6,0,0,0,2.69.46c8.57,0,22.6-11.71,39.66-28.75v38.74c0,2.32,1.45,3.89,4.65,4.58a9.54,9.54,0,0,0,2.76.38c27.92,0,100.35-102.12,159.33-137.56v-50.19c-59,35.45-131.41,137.56-159.33,137.56-.32,0-.63,0-.94-.06,34.71-35.63,79.85-88.55,117.34-111.21a19.29,19.29,0,0,1,.71,5.31V1124a19.34,19.34,0,0,0-.71-5.31c-14.82,9-30.84,22.65-46.94,38.13v-50.09a19.87,19.87,0,0,0-.26-3.21c-18,10.69-35.53,24.48-52.13,39.32v-42a7.25,7.25,0,0,0-.49-2.73c-71.58,49-164.41,125.83-180.6,170a39.85,39.85,0,0,0-3.23,15.86v50.18a39.84,39.84,0,0,1,3.23-15.85C2390.4,1278.47,2467.63,1211.88,2535.2,1163.26Zm74.05-6.39c-48.06,46.21-96.8,108.37-116.53,108.37a7.6,7.6,0,0,1-2.69-.46,6.68,6.68,0,0,1-2.92-1.19c31.51-33.58,75.3-82.15,121.88-109.84A19.9,19.9,0,0,1,2609.25,1156.87Z" style="fill:#00a599" />
    <path d="M2383.42,1333.68c-63.3,69-127.15,151.09-171.72,211.09h0c-25.43-63.24-36.74-120.62-36.74-172.62v50.18c0,52,11.31,109.38,36.74,172.62,44.57-60,108.42-142.13,171.72-211.09Z" style="fill:#00a599" />
    <path d="M2273.36,1562.19v50.19c493.93-122.51,616.84-310.5,616.84-460.48v-50.19C2890.2,1251.69,2767.29,1439.68,2273.36,1562.19Z" style="fill:#00a599" />
    <path d="M1957.87,1444c-25.25-14.31-6-51.85-50.41-77L1716.79,1258.9c-68.46-38.79-165.43-58-231.45-58-24.47,0-44.69,2.64-57.62,7.9V1259c12.93-5.27,33.15-7.91,57.62-7.91,66,0,163,19.23,231.45,58l190.67,108.07c44.38,25.14,25.16,62.68,50.41,77,66,37.43,114.46,68.4,185.1,108.44,8.16,4.62,16.48,9.19,24.88,13.71v-50.19c-8.4-4.52-16.72-9.09-24.88-13.71C2072.33,1512.36,2023.9,1481.39,1957.87,1444Z" style="fill:#00a599" />
    <path d="M1098.79,1039v50.19c0,165.7,135.34,483.1,912.18,549.21-131.77,30.76-299.74,71.44-428.33,107.6-6.48.06-12.81.33-19.18.33-18.27,0-36.73-2.21-55.9-4.43s-39.13-4.43-60.32-4.43a259.31,259.31,0,0,0-52.37,5.12c-71.65,14.7-147.44,56.85-147.44,87.8v50.19c0-31,75.79-73.1,147.44-87.8a258.59,258.59,0,0,1,52.37-5.12c21.19,0,41.12,2.21,60.32,4.43s37.63,4.42,55.9,4.42c6.37,0,12.7-.26,19.18-.32,154.13-43.34,364.86-93.18,502-124.65v-27.76q12.2.75,24.55,1.43V1595C1245.39,1548.2,1098.79,1211.43,1098.79,1039Z" style="fill:#00a599" />
    <path d="M1296.32,2005c-146.26,0-272-21.28-346.52-40.09v50.19c74.47,18.81,200.26,40.09,346.52,40.09,263.78,0,594.16-69.19,810.37-346.83V1658.2C1890.48,1935.83,1560.1,2005,1296.32,2005Z" style="fill:#00a599" />

    <path d="M2535.2,1114.16c-43.64,42.91-77.89,86.8-90.84,86.8-3.25-.68-4.71-2.42-4.71-5v50.19c0,2.62,1.46,4.36,4.71,5,7.46,0,22-14.56,41.3-35.1v45.56c0,2.23,1.36,3.7,4.37,4.27a7.6,7.6,0,0,0,2.69.46c8.57,0,22.6-11.71,39.66-28.75v38.74c0,2.33,1.45,3.9,4.65,4.58a9.54,9.54,0,0,0,2.76.38c27.92,0,100.35-102.11,159.33-137.56v-50.19c-59,35.45-131.41,137.57-159.33,137.57-.32,0-.63,0-.94-.07,34.71-35.63,79.85-88.55,117.34-111.21a19.34,19.34,0,0,1,.71,5.31v-50.19a19.34,19.34,0,0,0-.71-5.31c-14.82,9-30.84,22.65-46.94,38.14v-50.1a19.87,19.87,0,0,0-.26-3.21c-18,10.69-35.53,24.48-52.13,39.33v-42a7.25,7.25,0,0,0-.49-2.73c-71.58,49-164.41,125.83-180.6,170.06a39.77,39.77,0,0,0-3.23,15.85v50.18a39.84,39.84,0,0,1,3.23-15.85C2390.4,1229.37,2467.63,1162.78,2535.2,1114.16Zm74.05-6.39c-48.06,46.21-96.8,108.38-116.53,108.38a7.83,7.83,0,0,1-2.69-.46,6.68,6.68,0,0,1-2.92-1.2c31.51-33.58,75.3-82.14,121.88-109.84A19.9,19.9,0,0,1,2609.25,1107.77Z" style="fill:#00c2a3" />
    <path d="M2383.42,1284.58c-63.3,69-127.15,151.09-171.72,211.09h0c-25.43-63.24-36.74-120.62-36.74-172.62v50.19c0,52,11.31,109.38,36.74,172.62,44.57-60,108.42-142.14,171.72-211.09Z" style="fill:#00c2a3" />
    <path d="M2273.36,1513.1v50.18c493.93-122.51,616.84-310.5,616.84-460.48v-50.19C2890.2,1202.6,2767.29,1390.58,2273.36,1513.1Z" style="fill:#00c2a3" />
    <path d="M1957.87,1394.86c-25.25-14.31-6-51.85-50.41-77L1716.79,1209.8c-68.46-38.79-165.43-58-231.45-58-24.47,0-44.69,2.64-57.62,7.9v50.19c12.93-5.26,33.15-7.91,57.62-7.91,66,0,163,19.24,231.45,58l190.67,108.07c44.38,25.14,25.16,62.68,50.41,77,66,37.43,114.46,68.4,185.1,108.44,8.16,4.62,16.48,9.19,24.88,13.71V1517c-8.4-4.53-16.72-9.1-24.88-13.72C2072.33,1463.26,2023.9,1432.29,1957.87,1394.86Z" style="fill:#00c2a3" />
    <path d="M1098.79,989.87v50.19c0,165.7,135.34,483.1,912.18,549.21-131.77,30.76-299.74,71.44-428.33,107.6-6.48.06-12.81.33-19.18.33-18.27,0-36.73-2.21-55.9-4.43s-39.13-4.43-60.32-4.43a258.63,258.63,0,0,0-52.37,5.13c-71.65,14.69-147.44,56.84-147.44,87.79v50.19c0-31,75.79-73.1,147.44-87.8a259.31,259.31,0,0,1,52.37-5.12c21.19,0,41.12,2.21,60.32,4.43s37.63,4.42,55.9,4.42c6.37,0,12.7-.26,19.18-.32,154.13-43.34,364.86-93.18,502-124.64v-27.77q12.2.75,24.55,1.43v-50.19C1245.39,1499.1,1098.79,1162.33,1098.79,989.87Z" style="fill:#00c2a3" />
    <path d="M1296.32,1955.92c-146.26,0-272-21.28-346.52-40.09V1966c74.47,18.81,200.26,40.09,346.52,40.09,263.78,0,594.16-69.19,810.37-346.82V1609.1C1890.48,1886.73,1560.1,1955.92,1296.32,1955.92Z" style="fill:#00c2a3" />

    <path d="M2535.2,1065.06c-43.64,42.91-77.89,86.8-90.84,86.8-3.25-.68-4.71-2.42-4.71-5V1197c0,2.62,1.46,4.36,4.71,5,7.46,0,22-14.57,41.3-35.11v45.56c0,2.23,1.36,3.7,4.37,4.28a7.83,7.83,0,0,0,2.69.46c8.57,0,22.6-11.72,39.66-28.75v38.74c0,2.32,1.45,3.89,4.65,4.57a9.54,9.54,0,0,0,2.76.39c27.92,0,100.35-102.12,159.33-137.57v-50.19c-59,35.45-131.41,137.57-159.33,137.57-.32,0-.63,0-.94-.07,34.71-35.63,79.85-88.54,117.34-111.21a19.34,19.34,0,0,1,.71,5.31v-50.18a19.36,19.36,0,0,0-.71-5.32c-14.82,9-30.84,22.66-46.94,38.14v-50.1a19.87,19.87,0,0,0-.26-3.21c-18,10.69-35.53,24.49-52.13,39.33v-42a7.25,7.25,0,0,0-.49-2.73c-71.58,49-164.41,125.83-180.6,170.06a39.81,39.81,0,0,0-3.23,15.85v50.19a39.77,39.77,0,0,1,3.23-15.85C2390.4,1180.27,2467.63,1113.68,2535.2,1065.06Zm74.05-6.39c-48.06,46.21-96.8,108.38-116.53,108.38a7.6,7.6,0,0,1-2.69-.46,6.68,6.68,0,0,1-2.92-1.2c31.51-33.57,75.3-82.14,121.88-109.84A19.9,19.9,0,0,1,2609.25,1058.67Z" style="fill:#4edeaa" />
    <path d="M2383.42,1235.48c-63.3,69-127.15,151.09-171.72,211.09h0C2186.27,1383.33,2175,1326,2175,1274v50.19c0,52,11.31,109.38,36.74,172.62,44.57-60,108.42-142.14,171.72-211.09Z" style="fill:#4edeaa" />
    <path d="M2273.36,1464v50.19c493.93-122.52,616.84-310.51,616.84-460.49v-50.19C2890.2,1153.5,2767.29,1341.49,2273.36,1464Z" style="fill:#4edeaa" />
    <path d="M1957.87,1345.76c-25.25-14.31-6-51.85-50.41-77L1716.79,1160.7c-68.46-38.79-165.43-58-231.45-58-24.47,0-44.69,2.64-57.62,7.9v50.19c12.93-5.26,33.15-7.9,57.62-7.9,66,0,163,19.23,231.45,58L1907.46,1319c44.38,25.14,25.16,62.68,50.41,77,66,37.43,114.46,68.4,185.1,108.44,8.16,4.62,16.48,9.19,24.88,13.71v-50.18c-8.4-4.53-16.72-9.1-24.88-13.71C2072.33,1414.16,2023.9,1383.19,1957.87,1345.76Z" style="fill:#4edeaa" />
    <path d="M1098.79,940.77V991c0,165.71,135.34,483.1,912.18,549.22-131.77,30.76-299.74,71.43-428.33,107.6-6.48,0-12.81.32-19.18.32-18.27,0-36.73-2.21-55.9-4.43s-39.13-4.43-60.32-4.43a258.63,258.63,0,0,0-52.37,5.13c-71.65,14.7-147.44,56.85-147.44,87.79v50.19c0-30.95,75.79-73.1,147.44-87.79a258.63,258.63,0,0,1,52.37-5.13c21.19,0,41.12,2.21,60.32,4.43s37.63,4.43,55.9,4.43c6.37,0,12.7-.27,19.18-.33,154.13-43.34,364.86-93.18,502-124.64v-27.77q12.2.75,24.55,1.43v-50.19C1245.39,1450,1098.79,1113.23,1098.79,940.77Z" style="fill:#4edeaa" />
    <path d="M1296.32,1906.82c-146.26,0-272-21.27-346.52-40.08v50.18c74.47,18.81,200.26,40.09,346.52,40.09,263.78,0,594.16-69.19,810.37-346.82V1560C1890.48,1837.63,1560.1,1906.82,1296.32,1906.82Z" style="fill:#4edeaa" />

    <path d="M2819.46,807.12c93.26,118.57,220.83,466.65-546.1,656.88,43.78-58.9,107.11-140.73,169-208.61a167.5,167.5,0,0,1,16.9-8.74c19.54-8.41,63.52-13.54,84.65-23.53,40-18.87,62-55.45,87.18-83.71,32.59-36.37,61.77-65,68-95-59,35.45-131.41,137.57-159.33,137.57a9.54,9.54,0,0,1-2.76-.39c-34.19-7.31,131.93-115.66,119.16-161.08-59.07,35.71-137.13,146.52-163.47,146.52a7.6,7.6,0,0,1-2.69-.46c-32.43-6.18,126.47-116.52,119-161.23-76.2,45.31-145,146.5-164.63,146.5-33.43-7,122.3-126.5,112-151.86-71.58,49-164.41,125.83-180.6,170.06-10.43,24.44,7.79,45.5,7.65,65.42-63.3,69-127.15,151.09-171.72,211.09C2025.62,983.83,2595.66,835.1,2819.46,807.12ZM1102.77,893.58c-26.43,147.86,54.43,551.64,1006.41,603.21l-681.46-386.21c12.93-5.26,33.15-7.9,57.62-7.9,66,0,163,19.23,231.45,58l190.67,108.07c44.38,25.14,25.16,62.68,50.41,77,66,37.43,114.46,68.4,185.1,108.45,8.16,4.61,16.48,9.18,24.87,13.71-80.07-493.2-677.18-576.57-982.11-576.58C1154.78,891.34,1126.86,892.2,1102.77,893.58Zm-153,973.16c74.47,18.81,200.26,40.08,346.52,40.08,263.78,0,594.16-69.19,810.37-346.82-143.5,33-365.52,85.67-516.19,129-18.51,15.74-30.3,33-47.69,45.68-38.09,27.89-115.24,51-182.07,51-48.92,0-92.31-12.39-110.84-44.41-18.05-31.13,66-80.71,145-96.91a258.63,258.63,0,0,1,52.37-5.13c21.19,0,41.12,2.21,60.32,4.43s37.63,4.43,55.9,4.43c6.37,0,12.7-.27,19.18-.32,154.13-43.35,364.86-93.19,502-124.65-114.15-15-217.6-21.67-311.13-21.67C1193.74,1501.43,992.42,1757.23,949.8,1866.74Z" style="fill:url(#m)" /></g>
</svg>
```

Then the result in Edge browser as below:

[image]

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your time you spent to help me. However, the illustration misses the gradients on sides now.:-(

Comment: Hi there, I have found the reason. It is the mix-blend-mode which is not supported by IE / Edge.